# Why does not the page load after a successful compilation?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

after importing an existing project to my IDE (webstorm) and installing dependencies, I run ionic serve with a successful compilation. even though, the page does not load.

in the browser, I get this message: "A web page is slowing down your browser. what would you like to do?"
I click the "stop it" button and I get this warning in the console withing the developer tools :

```
Error: Script terminated by timeout at:
getInjectableDef@http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:34163:5
resolveNgModuleDep@http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:55246:35
./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js/NgModuleRef_.prototype.get@http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:55950:16
resolveNgModuleDep@http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:55261:29
./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js/NgModuleRef_.prototype.get@http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:55950:16
resolveNgModuleDep@http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:55261:29
./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js/NgModuleRef_.prototype.get@http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:55950:16
resolveNgModuleDep@http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:55261:29
./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js/NgModuleRef_.prototype.get@http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:55950:16
resolveNgModuleDep@http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:55261:29
./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js/NgModuleRef_.prototype.get@http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:55950:16
resolveNgModuleDep@http://localhost:8100/vendor.…
```

**Solution:**

the problem caused by a bad implementation of lazy loading feature.

let's suppose A is a component and B and C are child ones

Bad implementation :

```
{
    {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: './a.module#aPageModule',
    },
    {
        path: 'b',
        loadChildren: './b/b.module#bPageModule'
    },
    {
        path: 'c',
        loadChildren: './c/c.module#cPageModule'
    }
}
```

Correct implementation :

```
{
    {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: './a.module#aPageModule',
        children: [
            {
                path: 'b',
                loadChildren: './b/b.module#bPageModule'
            },
            {
                path: 'c',
                loadChildren: './c/c.module#cPageModule'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: seems you are re-requesting the same references over and over again. Any chance you could build your solution in a non-minified way and really take a look at what is happening?

Comment: I solved the problem. it caused by a wrong implementation of the lazy loading feature